# C# property explicit set versus override get

Tags: c#, properties, overriding

Short: Writing a base class property, do we prefer an explicit `set` method or an override of `get` method?

I have a base class for my Pages.  It implements several "features"; some instances may want to disable the feature, and this is known at design-time (i.e. it will not change).  The base class looks like this:

```
public class MyPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  void Method()
  {
    if (Feature1)
      DoSomething1();
  }
}
```

The question is: which of the following two approaches for defining the `Feature1` property is preferred:

```
// In MyPage class
private bool _feature1 = true;
protected bool Feature1
{
  get { return _feature1; }
  set { _feature1 = value; }
}

// In Derived page class, somewhere early
Feature1 = false;
```

versus:

```
// In MyPage class
protected virtual bool Feature1
{
  get { return true; }
}

// In Derived page class
protected override bool Feature1
{
  get { return false; }
}
```

In the first case, the property has an explicit `set` for the derived Page to call; in the second case the property has no `set` but instead allows the derived Page to override the `get`.  Do we have a preference?

This choice is applicable in more general C# cases than mine with Pages, but it shows I am limited in some ways (e.g. I'm not doing `new`, I'm not in charge of the constructor, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it certainly *sounds* like you intend that to be a readonly field.

In such a case, only defining the `get` half of the property, and overriding it in the derived classes would be appropriate.

This also has the benefit of having a *compile-time* error as opposed to *run-time* error if someone tries to set it.

Of course, if its *not* supposed to be read-only, then you would need to implement the setter.

Comment: This is indeed the decision I have made so far!  For precisely the reasons you state.  I like to understand the advised style/theory.  Effectively, the `get` plus `set` approach is using a variable in the base to determine the `get` result, while the `get`-only plus `virtual/override` approach is using sub-classing instead of a variable.  That is what I was thinking about.

Comment: @JonBrave Technically they are both using subclassing. The difference is that `get` only is returning a *constant* value (in this implementation), whereas get/set is obviously returning a *variable* value. If the field is readonly, then returning a constant value makes sense.

Comment: Yes, you put it better than I could summarise in a 500-odd character comment!  I like to think that the get-only-override approach is saving me the overhead of storing a variable, though I guess the override call might outweigh that :)

Comment: @JonBrave An entry in the vTable against a boolean variable, the difference will obviously be so ridiculously tiny as to be negligible in all cases (I assume you already know this, but noting this for future readers).

Answer (score 0):

Use an auto property and set the value in the constructor.

```
protected bool Feature1 { get; set; } 

// Your Constructor    
public YourClassName(bool featureState)
{
     Feature1 = featureState;
}
```

Comment: I accept that your auto-constructor is a neater/earlier way to set the property than my example.  However, in itself it does not answer whether/why an explicit `set` is or is not preferable to an overridden `get`, which is what I am looking for opinions on?

Comment: Further, the solution must not involve passing parameters to the constructor.  First, as I said, I do not do the construction (the framework does); also, my choice of `Feature1` hinted that I may have many such "features", I do not want to pass loads of parameters (yes, I know I could use named...)

Comment: I think it's a question of style and as long as it is consistent throughout your application both patterns are fine. I lean towards avoiding overriding so that the developer has to be deliberate around how they use the property. If the override is deleted or missed then you will still get a compilation pass and potentially passing tests even though the behavior is not as intended. i.e. The explicit set is safer in my opinion, especially when multiple people are working on the codebase.

Comment: @JonBrave much of your approach will really depend on the "side effects" setting the property will have on your class.  If you want to ensure the "Feature" cannot be changed after the class is instantiated then only the get accessor needs to be virtual, otherwise both get and set should be virtual, and perhaps even a protected set

Answer (score 0):

It's better to override the `set` as well. As it has no function in the derived class you or someone else may want to set the value which has no effect in this case and then in few days or weeks later you wonder why it's setting the `Feature1` not working as desired. So you'd better throw an exception if someone tries to set it:

```
override bool Feature1
{
    get { return true; }
    set { throw new InvalidOperationException("In this implementation 'Feature1' is read-only."); }
}
```

Example:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool baseFeature1a = new Base1().Feature1; // false
        bool baseFeature1b = (new Derived1() as Base1).Feature1; // true

        bool baseFeature2a = new Base1().Feature2; // false
        bool baseFeature2b = (new Derived1() as Base1).Feature2; // true
    }
}

class Base1
{
    private bool feature2 = false;

    public virtual bool Feature1
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public virtual bool Feature2
    {
        get { return feature2; }
        protected set { feature2 = value; }
    }
}

class Derived1 : Base1
{
    public Derived1()
    {
        Feature2 = true;
    }

    public override bool Feature1
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are going for my second case, where the base virtual property has a `get` but (very deliberately) no `set`.  This was intended to prevent a `set` at compile-time (not just runtime error).  I had assumed my code would prevent any `set`, are you saying that an overridden property can have a `set` even if the base property does not define one?

Comment: Yes. See my updated answer. You can try it yourself ;-)

Comment: Umm, your new Example is now different.  You are now using both an explicit `set` and a virtual/override, my original question was to use either one approach or the other.  And for my response above, you now have a `set` in the base and no `set` in the derived, I know how that works, I was questioning what happens if you have a `set` in the derived but not in the base (i.e. as per your first box, combined with my code).  So your code may well be fine, but I think we're losing the thread....

Comment: Ahh... now I get it (I think). In this case the base class property will be read-only and the derived class will allow you to set it. I've updated the example.

Comment: You might not be in charge of the constructor but you must specify the type you want to create. If anything is overriden is will be the current method/property it means it will have the precendence. If you create a Base class you cannot expect it to behave like the derived class. I made another update.

Comment: I thank you for your comments.  But you have gone down a different track.  My original question is, approximately: (assuming you have control of both base & derived), and you want derived to produce a `get` result different from the default one in base, is it preferable for base to offer a `set` for derived to call or for base to offer a **virtual** `get` for derived to **override**?

Comment: This is up to you wether you want to allow the base value to be changed or not. If yes you can provide a setter and change the base property value in the derived class. I often do this for a Name property that has a public getter but a protected setter and set a different name in the derived class. If you however never plan to change its value then it can also be without a setter and you override if you want to return something else. This is not only about the precedence but also about the preference. It's a disign question. Neither solution is betther than the other.

Comment: Yep, it is indeed a question about design preference (to see if anybody has opinions)!  Thank you for your comments.